# How to set Raphael Path ID

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am basically worse then a noob on Raphael. I was wondering how to set the path ID for the following code. I did some googling but couldn't find any way to set ID to the following code, since it uses an array.

```
var mySVG=['exampleDOMid',400,400,
{
    "type":"path","fill":"#C4C5C7","path":"path code here","stroke":"none"
},{
    "type":"path","fill":"#EDEDEE","path":"path code here","stroke":"none"
},{
    "type":"path","fill":"#5A5B5D","path":"path code here","stroke":"none"
},{
    "type":"path","fill":"#231F20","path":"path code here","stroke":"none"
}];

var r = Raphael(mySVG);
```

I generated the code from http://toki-woki.net/p/SVG2RaphaelJS/ by submitting a SVG file

Comment: Can't you use the position in the array as ID?

Comment: I am not sure, but is position same as ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, it depends how you want to use that id. 
1. If you need the ID just for some precedence of events, then just use the position in the array
2. To have something specific, just add this to your path:

```
path.data("id", id);
```

Then you can retrieve the id by doing the following:

```
var index = path.data("id");
```

Also look into Raphael documentation for data() function for more details.